# Chrome Extension windows invisible

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, google-chrome-extensions

When I click the extension icons in the toolbar, rather than showing the window for the extension, nothing is displayed.  However, if I roll over where the window will be, the cursor behaves as if it is rolling over links.  It seems like the extension windows are all transparent.

[image: Clicked button, but no window displayed]

Has anyone seen this and know how to fix it?  The extensions seem to work fine on my other computers.

**Update:  Significant discovery, but problem not solved...**

It turns out that if the browser window is open on my main monitor, the extension windows show up fine.  However, if the browser window is on one of my other monitors, the extension windows do not display.  At least I now have a workaround as I can temporarily move the browser window to my main monitor, but a permanent solution would be appreciated if anyone has any idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Does this happen for each extension or one in particular?

Comment: It happens for every extension.

Comment: Try disabling all extensions except for one, try to choose a popular one. If the menu appears, keep adding extensions one at a time until it breaks again. This is likely caused by an extension.

Comment: Already tried that.  It happens even if I only have a single extension enabled, regardless which extension it is.